# How to bypass VPN for local networks in Windows 7? (static route not working)

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, routing

I want to access my local network 192.168.1.* while the VPN (connected via Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client) is active, I tried the following command but no luck

```
route -p add 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 192.168.1.1
```

Here's my route table

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.90     25
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.10.1.1      10.10.1.200      2
        10.10.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       10.10.1.200    257
      10.10.1.200  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.10.1.200    257
      10.10.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.10.1.200    257
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
   153.122.13.102  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1     192.168.1.90     26
      192.168.1.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.90     26
     192.168.1.90  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.90    281
     192.168.43.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.43.1    276
     192.168.56.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    266
    192.168.164.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.164.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.164.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.43.1    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.90    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.10.1.200    257
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.164.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.43.1    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.1.90    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.10.1.200    257
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.10.1.1       1
      192.168.0.0      255.255.0.0      192.168.1.1       1
===========================================================================
```

Comment: Give this a try but without the persistent `-p` switch to start and see if this gives you the expected result. 1.) `route -p change 0.0.0.0 MASK 0.0.0.0 10.1.10.1 metric 10` and then 2.) `route -p change 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1 metric 5`. Essentially give the local network subnet a lower metric than the VPN subnet assuming `10.10.1.1` GW is for VPN and the `192.168.1.1` is for the local network.... Give it a shot and hit me back if that helps and I'll post as an answer with more detail, etc.